# pyspark group by and pivot TypeError

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, pivot

I have a dataframe with header on Pyspark using Jupyter Notebook:

```
|    device_id       |   date   |   ad_id            |event_type|country|  brand|

|7a8ff5a545534e109...|2018-06-26|c67ef34fb59e47df9...|      load| A     |Brand D|
|c4c91e7021da40bea...|2018-12-23|e5ae45c4c0ae4ab09...|     close| B     |Brand E|
|8e425095de124f709...|2018-06-30|e5ae45c4c0ae4ab09...|      load| C     |Brand C|
|6c4375bd360f4a2e8...|2018-11-18|474658ce06464bd79...|     close| D     |Brand A|
|b5c54d0637a747b6a...|2018-08-13|cf8f7b43101e44e48...|   display| A     |Brand A|
```

I would like to group by 'device_id','date','country','brand' and pivot event_type:

```
df3=df1.groupby('device_id','date','country','brand').pivot("event_type").count("ad_id")
```

I get this error:

```
**TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-e46231adee1a> in <module>
----> 1 df3=df1.groupby('device_id','country','brand').pivot("event_type").count("app_id")
TypeError: _api() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**
```

What's wrong? I want to get device_id, date, country, brand, load_count, close_count, display_count.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `count` with no argument as below,

```
df1.groupby('device_id','date','country','brand')\
   .pivot("event_type")\
   .count()
```

Or, Try with `agg` aggregator as below,

```
df1=spark.createDataFrame([ ("7a8ff5a545534e109", "2018-06-26", "c67ef34fb59e47df9", "load", "A", "Brand D"),
                           ("c4c91e7021da40bea", "2018-12-23", "e5ae45c4c0ae4ab09", "close", "B", "Brand E")],
                         ["device_id", "date", "ad_id", "event_type", "country", "brand"])

+-----------------+----------+-----------------+----------+-------+-------+     
|device_id        |date      |ad_id            |event_type|country|brand  |
+-----------------+----------+-----------------+----------+-------+-------+
|7a8ff5a545534e109|2018-06-26|c67ef34fb59e47df9|load      |A      |Brand D|
|c4c91e7021da40bea|2018-12-23|e5ae45c4c0ae4ab09|close     |B      |Brand E|
+-----------------+----------+-----------------+----------+-------+-------+


df3=df1.groupby('device_id','date','country','brand') \
       .pivot("event_type") \
       .agg(count("ad_id"))

+-----------------+----------+-------+-------+-----+----+
|        device_id|      date|country|  brand|close|load|
+-----------------+----------+-------+-------+-----+----+
|c4c91e7021da40bea|2018-12-23|      B|Brand E|    1|null|
|7a8ff5a545534e109|2018-06-26|      A|Brand D| null|   1|
+-----------------+----------+-------+-------+-----+----+
```